# Copying rows error message "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I am trying to transfer data from one row to another within phpmyadmin, but when I attempt i I get the following error message.

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Code I attempt :

```
INSERT INTO users_links 
    (`username`,`facebook`)
    SELECT 
    (`username`,`facebook`)
    FROM users2
```

However when I try this it works but Its not what I want.

```
INSERT INTO users_links 
        `username`
        SELECT 
        `username`
        FROM users2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO users_links (`username`, `facebook`)
SELECT `username`, `facebook`
FROM users2
```

Comment: Perfect! it works! so it was a simple syntax error?

Comment: Yes it was a syntax problem.